# How to make separate rows in Pandas by column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
    name    total
    bob     10
```

What I need is this: What is the best way to achieve this?

```
 name   total
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
  bob     1
```

Comment: could you explain more about what you want to do? the second dataframe grouped goes to the first one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['bob'], 
...                    'total': [10]}, 
...                   index = [0]) 
>>> df
    name    total
0   bob     10
```

We can use the `repeat` function on the value from `total` like so :

```py
>>> df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.total)].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   name total
0   bob 10
1   bob 10
2   bob 10
3   bob 10
4   bob 10
5   bob 10
6   bob 10
7   bob 10
8   bob 10
9   bob 10
```

And set `total` to one to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['total'] = 1
>>> df
   name total
0   bob 1
1   bob 1
2   bob 1
3   bob 1
4   bob 1
5   bob 1
6   bob 1
7   bob 1
8   bob 1
9   bob 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this programmatically, one approach is:

```
import numpy as np
df['total'] = df['total'].apply(lambda x: np.repeat([1], x))
df.explode('total')
```

output:

```
  name total
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
0  bob     1
```

If you need the index to be unique, add `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
df['total'] = df['total'].apply(lambda x: np.repeat([1], x))
df.explode('total').reset_index(drop=True).to_clipboard(0)


  name total
0  bob     1
1  bob     1
2  bob     1
3  bob     1
4  bob     1
5  bob     1
6  bob     1
7  bob     1
8  bob     1
9  bob     1
```